# Counting button keystrokes using apps script in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, keystrokes

I'm trying to register a count in a Google spreadsheet every time a particular key is pressed on the keyboard.  What Apps Script should I be using?

Example:

- If I press ">" a '1' is entered into Cell A1, pressing ">" again either increments Cell A1 by '1' to value '2' OR enters a '1' into Cell A2
- If I press "<" a 1 is input into Cell B1, pressing "<" again either increments Cell B1 by '1' to value '2' OR enters a '1' into Cell B2
- The up or down keys operate in a similar way in Cells C1 and D1 respectively.

Should I be publishing code/app to a Site?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

apps script does not support detecting keystrokes in the sheets interface.
instead you need to build a webapp (as a dialog, sidebar or separate window) and type there.